# How to select multiple values in select2 control by jquery?

Tags: jquery, select2

I want to select multiple options in a select2 multivalue control, when clicking a button.
This is useful specially for searches where the user needs to select many option to one of the filters

any idea how to achieve it..? 
I found how to select an option in select2 single option dropdown, but not in a multiselect control for several options at the same time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I found the way. It's just passing an array of option values to 'val' argument:

```
$('#my_select2').select2('val', ["value1", "value2", "value3"]);
```

Comment: an anonymous users just posted this as an alternative solution:


var data = {
    id: 1,
    text: 'Barn owl'
};
var newOption = new Option(data.text, data.id, false, false);
$('#mySelect2').append(newOption).trigger('change');


this solution is referenced from https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items#creating-new-options-in-the-dropdown

Answer (score 1):

you can also do it this way by defining javascript array.

```
var Values = new Array();
Values.push("value1");
Values.push("value2");
Values.push("value3");

$("#my_select2").val(Values).trigger('change');
```