# How can I trigger a selection for a Select2 EntityRef element via javascript?

Tags: developer, forms, javascript, select2, entityref

The CiviCRM [EntityRef](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/EntityRef+Fields) form element uses a [Select2](https://select2.github.io/) select box to make lots of CiviCRM forms more awesome. A user can, for example, search for contacts to choose one. Great.

I am building an extension where I would like to take an EntityRef element from a core form and select a use javascript to select a specific entity (or multiple entities in the case of a multi-select). Is there a javascript function I can call in order to trigger such a selection (by passing in the ID of the entity, for example)?

Comment: Have you seen https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/18627/how-to-select-multiple-values-in-select2-control-by-jquery ?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this related question](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/18627/how-to-select-multiple-values-in-select2-control-by-jquery), it should be possible to do this via:

```
$('#id-of-select2').select2('val', 'value-to-select');
```

or, if you want to select multiple items in a multiselect:

```
$('#id-of-select2').select2('val', ['value-to-select', 'another-value']);
```